# Jquery: is there another way to write this, maybe using .attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, href

I thought I could re-write the line below:

```
$('a').filter('[hash=' + inview + ']');
```

to something like this:

```
$('a').attr(href, inview);
```

obviously with `var inview = yada yada yada` defined above it.

or is there another way to write the first line up there,

**using jquery and getting rid of the `[hash='` for something like .attr or .something(inview)?**

Comment: jQuery's attr() function gets and sets a mix of HTML attributes and DOM properties depending on which one it thinks you might want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a[hash=' + inview + ']');
```

That should do it.

Comment: but is there another way to do it, without using `[hash=`?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
$('a[hash="' + inview + '"]')
```

`$('a').attr('hash', inview);`, which is what I assume you meant for your second line, actually *sets* the hash attribute to inview.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').attr(href, inview);
```

For reference that would set the href of all a elements to inview

Comment: Good catch, I thought we'd just assume that.